# remove div elements if the div length is more than one using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do we remove  `div` elements, if it there are more than one? Below is my page structure.

```
<div class='mydiv'></div>
<div class='mydiv'></div>
<div class='mydiv'></div>
<div class='mydiv'></div>
<div class='mydiv'></div>
<div class='mydiv'></div>

var countdiv = $(".mydiv").length;
if(countdiv > 1){
  var result = countdiv - 1; //answer is 5
  //remove the 5 remaining divs so that only one will appear in the page. 
}
```

Thanks, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$('.mydiv').slice(1).remove()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gd8TS/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var countdiv = $(".mydiv").length;
if(countdiv > 1){
  $(".mydiv:gt(0)").remove();//all .mydiv other than first will be removed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) with [:gt-selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) like,,

```
var countdiv = $(".mydiv").length;
if(countdiv > 1){
  $(".mydiv:gt(0)").remove();
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DBERV/)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this,

Simply :

```
  $(".mydiv:gt(0)").remove();
```

Another method:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function(){                                                               
                        var countdiv = $(".mydiv").length;
                         var i=1;
                        $(".mydiv").each(function(){

                            if(countdiv!=i){
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                            i++;

                        });


                    });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

**Method 1: Using CSS give**

```
    .mydiv{
      display: none;
    }
    .mydiv:first-child{
      display: block;
    }
```

**Method 2: Using JS **

```
.mydiv{
          display: none;
        }

$( ".mydiv:first-child" ).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$(".mydiv").slice(1).remove();
```

If there is more than 1 ".mydiv" elements it will keep the first and apply remove to the rest of them.